# Laravel 5 sentinel: How can disable "activation" and "throttle" checkpoints?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, sentinel

is there a way to disable "activation" and "throttle" check in sentinel?

Thank you for any help you can provide for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find a checkpoints array on sentinel config and comment it.

```
'checkpoints' => [

    //'throttle',
    //'activation',

],
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

> Open file Kernel.php from "app/Http/"

and comment it

```
  'api' => [
        //'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```